# Android studio and Nexus repository with CI GitLab

Tags: android, kotlin, gitlab, nexus

I have the android project in my company.
I wanna use Nexus proxy repository. 4 repositories in Nexus are configurated. I edit my buld.gradle file where I specify:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google {url"${nexusUrl}/repository/google-maven2/"}
        jcenter {url"${nexusUrl}/repository/maven-jcenter/"}
        maven {url"${nexusUrl}/repository/maven-kotlinx/"}
        maven {url"${nexusUrl}/repository/maven-jitpack/"}
    }
}
```

When I build my project I expect from fiddler4 that android studio will try to get access to Nexus server for getting libraries. However I don't see it.
I need it for CI with GitLab. Furthermore, in GitLab pipeline log I see that it will try to get access to native locations of the libraries(Example: > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.)

Comment: What is your question? It might help you to review [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What does "I don't see it" mean?  404?